# $state.go method not switching to other state - angularjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, states

In my controller, I have  `$state.go('purchase');`, but am having the following error :

`Error: Could not resolve`*`'purchase'`*`from state ''.`

But initially, I defined url `''` to `'/home'` in my file states.js, which goes to state 'home'. Why is my state transition not happening? Please let me know where I am wrong.

**states.js**

```
/**
 * Dashboard routes.
 */
define(['./templates'], function(templates) {
    var mod = angular.module("item.states", ["ui.router"]);
    console.log("Inside item home states");

    var StateProvider = function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
         $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/home');
        $stateProvider            
            .state("item", {
                url: '/home',
                template: templates.home,
                controller : 'controller.item.home.main'
            })
            .state("purchase", {
                url: '/purchase',
                template: templates.purchase,
                controller : 'controller.item.home.main'
            });
    }
    StateProvider.$inject = ["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider"];

    mod.config(StateProvider);
    return mod;
});
```

**controller.js**

```
function _purchase(_event){
console.log("Clicked purchase button");
$state.go('purchase');
}
```

**main.js**

```
define(['./controllers','./states'], function(controllers,states) {
  var mod = angular.module("item.home", ['common.services.ItemService',
     'common.filters.format']);
  mod.controller('controller.item.home.main', controllers.main);
  console.log("Inside item home main");
  return mod;
});
```

**my server side jade**

```
extends ../layouts/default
block content
    div(ng-controller="controller.item.home.main as main" ng-init="item= #{JSON.stringify(item)}")
        .masterhead.segment
            .ui.page.grid.stackable
                .row.ui.basic.segment
                    .four.wide.column.ui.center.aligned
                        img.ui.image.rounded(src="/images/itemicon.png")
                        h2() !{item.name} - !{item.activeseason.name}
                    .twelve.wide.column
                        .ui.small.orange.button(id="purchaseBtn" ng-click="purchase($event)”)
                                | Purchase
        div.ui.page.grid(ui-view)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because,
In my main.js - I missed to include the module 'item.states'

```
define(['./controllers','./states'], function(controllers,states) {
  var mod = angular.module("item.home", ['common.services.ItemService',
     'common.filters.format','item.states']);
  mod.controller('controller.item.home.main', controllers.main);
  console.log("Inside item home main");
  return mod;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

use transition to

> $state.transitionTo('purchase')

and change syntax error in yor code

```
            url: '/purchase,
```

to

> ```
>     url: '/purchase',
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the syntax you are using and why defining your routes inside a template, but I'd recommend another way to do it, create a file on the 'module folder' or your root folder and define your routes in a more 'general' way like the following:

```
'use strict';

//Setting up route
angular.module('mainModule').config(['$stateProvider',
    function($stateProvider) {
        // main module state routing
        $stateProvider.
        state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'controller.item.home.main', //I'd recommend to use plain html files, instead something rendered in the server
            controller:'HomeController'
        }).
        state('purchase', {
            url: '/purchase',
            templateUrl: 'templates.purchase', 
            controller: 'purchaseController'
        });
    }
]);
```

I guess in your home controller:

```
angular.module('mainModule').controller('HomeController', ['$scope','$state',
    function($scope,$state) {
        $scope.onclick = function(){
            $state.go('purchase');
        };
}]);
```

on the other side your states are not related to your server side at all.